# How Do I Display Placeholder Text When No Documents Match User in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I have a script that runs through a collection of photo documents, checks if they match the current user ID, and then renders the template.

```
<ul id="settings-photos">
    {{#each photos}}
        {{#if person}}
            {{> photo}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

If no photos exist for a user, I would like to display a "Click to upload a photo!" message. How would I write a condition for this in the Spacebars/Meteor way?

My `person`helper code is as follows

```
person : function () {
    user = Meteor.userId();
    photoUser = this.user;
    console.log(this);
    if(user == photoUser) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have accepted the answer that led me to the solution. My final script was

```
photos : function () {
    var id = Meteor.userId();
    var photos = Photos.find({user: id}).fetch();

    return photos;
}
```

and then in HTML

```
<ul id="settings-photos">
    {{#each photos}}
        {{> photo}}
    {{/each}}
    {{#unless photos}}
        Click to upload an image
    {{/unless}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing a loop through photo collection and checking for user will work, a better way of doing it would be to write a UI/Template helper which extracts the photo of user. That way, if you end up changing the schema of user, or photo collection, you only need to change the helper.

```
Template.registerHelper(userPhoto, function(userId){
    var userPhoto = Photos.findOne({person: userId});
    if(userPhoto && userPhoto.photoUrl) {
        return userPhoto.photoUrl;
    }
})
```

This way you can write your template much more cleanly. As in,

```
<ul id="settings-photos">
    {{#if userPhoto currentUser._id}}
        {{> userPhoto currentUser._id}}
    {{else}}
        <a href="#">No Photos found. Click here to upload</a>
    {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Original Answer:

---

```
<ul id="settings-photos">
    {{#each photos}}
        {{#if person}}
            {{> photo}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    {{#unless photos}}
        <a href="#">No Photos found. Click here to upload</a>
    {{/unless}}
</ul>
```

Comment: That is close, but photos is a collection of all users' photos and it's the `person` helper that checks to make sure it's the right one. `#unless` will only trigger in this case if no users have photos uploaded.

Comment: Ah, your first solution works flawlessly as long as I change my photos helper to only return based on the correct user ID and then get rid of if person. I'll accept this and post my completed script in my question

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  isPhoto: function(person){
    // your condition
    return true/false;
 }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#if isPhoto person}}
 {{> Photo}}
{{else}}
 Click to upload a photo!
{{/if}}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you haven't added an explaination on how this works and its not so constructive.